# How to find the shortest and longest strings from a list of string inputs

Tags: java

I first need to receive an unknown number of string inputs from a user and create a loop that will terminate when "x" is entered
I need to keep track of how many inputs are entered
I need to test the inputs to get the longest and shortest string and their length
I need to find the sum of string lengths
I need to find the average string length
I need to find the number of strings entered excluding "x"

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, take a look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/133203) for info on *how* to ask homework questions.

Comment: Please try to do it first and then come here for debug/help.

Answer (score 1):

firstly let me highlight, you should really to try to implement it on your own first, because otherwise you will never understand properly to the logic / syntax,..

Without storing values can be done like follows:

> I am just only not sure if average length will work properly, but looks like it should
>
> (check the commented calculation in the code, it's not working this way, print at the end probably works)

```
public static void getStringsAndGetDetails() {
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689213/i-would-like-to-find-out-how-to-find-the-shortest-and-longest-strings-from-a-lis
    System.out.println("Put 'x' or 'X' for exit");
    String input ="";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String shortestStr = null;
    String longestStr = null;

    int counter = 0;
    //int averageLength = 0;

    //load till x or X is entered 
    do{
        //read
        System.out.print("please, enter input: ");
        input = sc.nextLine();

        //avoid to process when escape is entered
        if(!input.toLowerCase().equals("x")) {
            counter++;

            //get to temp variable, can be reused with avoid repeating reading
            int inputLength = input.length();

            //if input is shorter then its new shortest, null check for first input
            if(shortestStr == null || inputLength < shortestStr.length()) {
                shortestStr = input;
            }

            //similar with longest string
            if(longestStr == null || inputLength > longestStr.length()) {
                longestStr = input;
            }

            //!! calculate average length is NOT possible like that, see bellow in printing
            /*
            averageLength = (averageLength + inputLength) / counter;
            System.out.println();
            */
        }
    }while(!input.toLowerCase().equals("x"));
    //not mandatory, but best practice (closing the streams), scanner in this case
    sc.close();


    System.out.println("Entered " + counter + " values");
    System.out.println("Longest: "+ longestStr);
    System.out.println("Shortest: "+ shortestStr);

    //be sure data are available (in case you enter x in first iteration, will fail otherwise)
    if(shortestStr != null && longestStr != null) {
    //seems to work
        int averageLength= (shortestStr.length() + longestStr.length()) / 2;  
        System.out.println("Average length: "+ averageLength);  
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Put 'x' or 'X' for exit
please, enter input: kakaka
please, enter input: ka
please, enter input: kaka
please, enter input: x
Entered 3 values
Longest: kakaka
Shortest: ka
Average length: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code bellow. It contains several good practices that you would hopefully implement in your programs. Notice how the tests are written in the main method? I have started with those, so I could think through the solution before writing the actual method. In the tests I try to capture as many edge cases as possible. If I find a bug in my code, I can then write a new unit test that will make it fail, and then fix the code.
Disclaimer: This code requires JUnit 5 added to your classpath.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class StringsInfo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringsInfo sInfo = new StringsInfo();

    sInfo.test(new String[] {}, null, null, 0, 0.0D, 0);
    sInfo.test(new String[] {null}, null, null, 0, 0.0D, 0);
    sInfo.test(new String[] {"one"}, "one", "one", 1, 3.0D, 3);
    sInfo.test(new String[] {"one", "two"}, "one", "one", 2, 3.0D, 6);
    sInfo.test(new String[] {"one", "two", "three"}, "one", "three", 3, (11/3), 11);
    sInfo.test(new String[] {"one", "two", "three", "x", "five"}, "one", "three", 3, (11/3), 11);
  }

  /**
   * Helper to test the class
   * @param input
   * @param shortest
   * @param longest
   * @param count
   * @param average
   * @param sumLength
   */
  private void test(String[] input, String shortest, String longest, long count,
      double average, long sumLength) {
    Result result = processString(input);
    assertEquals(shortest, result.shortest);
    assertEquals(longest, result.longest);
    assertEquals(count, result.count);
    assertTrue(average == result.average);
    assertEquals(sumLength, result.sumLength);
  }

  private Result processString(String[] input) {
    Result result = new Result();
    int shortestLength = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int longestLength = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (String s : input) {
      if (s == null) { // Ignore null Strings
        continue;
      }
      if ("x".equals(s)) { // found the end
        break;
      }
      result.count++;
      int wordLength = s.length();
      result.sumLength += wordLength;
      if (wordLength < shortestLength) {
        result.shortest = s;
        shortestLength = wordLength;
      }
      if (wordLength > longestLength) {
        result.longest = s;
        longestLength = wordLength;
      }
    }
    if (result.count > 0) { // avoid division by zero
      result.average = result.sumLength / result.count;
    }
    return result;
  }

}

/**
 * Helper class to store the result
 */
class Result {
  String shortest;
  String longest;
  long count;
  double average;
  long sumLength;
}
```

Comment: hi fpezzini, with this question I cannot store anything in an array